# Magento Adminhtml: Where do forms come from?

Tags: model-view-controller, magento

My question comes from [seeing this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31477/limit-magento-title-length-in-admin#comment30618_31477) and not being able to find the correct answer.

When adding a new product, where does the actual code come from for the input fields? In the aforementioned question, the desire is to add maxlength attribute to the input box. I dug around for over an hour and did find plenty of form helpers but not the one for this exact case.

How do I find the true origin of this (or any) form in Magento?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, majority of Magento's form fields come from `Varian_Data_Form` However you can easily specify a maxlength property via a higher up call, as in:

```
$fieldset->addField('title', 'text', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('form')->__('Title3'),
          'maxlength' => '30', // <-- change here
          'class'     => 'required-entry',
          'required'  => true,
          'name'      => 'title',
          'onclick' => "alert('on click');",
          'onchange' => "alert('on change');",
          'style'   => "border:10px",
          'value'  => 'hello !!',
          'disabled' => false,
          'readonly' => true,
          'after_element_html' => '<small>Comments</small>',
          'tabindex' => 1
        ));
```

Example (and modified) from:

- http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-admin-form-field

Related:

- [Extend a Varien Form Element for a Custom Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9255213/extend-a-varien-form-element-for-a-custom-module)
- [Is it good practice to add own file in lib/Varien/Data/Form/Element folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073891/is-it-good-practice-to-add-own-file-in-lib-varien-data-form-element-folder)

Comment: Right but take my example, exactly where is the code like above generated which builds THAT form? If it is generically from `Varien_Data_Form`, what tells it the proper IDs, etc, for the add new product form itself. I like to think I don't suck at Magento and this is nagging at me.

Answer (score 0):

I accepted B00MER's answer because it led me to what I believe to be the Real Answer...

Clicking on the links he listed, the pattern of `$fieldset->addField` presented itself as a key way to `grep` in files.

```
user@magento:~/www/app$ grep -rin "addField.*text" * | grep -i product
code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Super/Config/Simple.php:140:        $fieldset->addField('simple_product_inventory_qty', 'text', array(
```

There were about a dozen results which were quickly narrowed down (we're not caring about giftcard or Attribute sets). I'm not 100% sure THIS file is the answer but it seems that some logic could be added to catch whether or not the input's `name=="Name"` and then a maxlength could then be added in.

Comment: The majority of the addFields attributes will map to the HTML attributes, so maxlength added to its parameters *should* cause the HTML counter part to be as the same. If you're needing more fine grained control, see Alans recommendation for such: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6077165/158325